# How to fetch last 24 hours records from database

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have `Orders` model which stores orders of users. I'd like to filter only orders which has been issued (`order_started` field) on the last 24 hours for a user. I am trying to update following view:

```
def userorders(request):
    Orders = Orders.objects.using('db1').filter(order_owner=request.user).extra(select={'order_ended_is_null': 'order_ended IS NULL',},)
```

Order model has following fields:

```
order_uid = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
order_owner = models.TextField()
order_started = models.DateTimeField()
order_ended = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

How can I add the extra filter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it as below, where you add another argument in the `filter` call   (assuming the rest of your function was working):

```
import datetime

def userorders(request):
    time_24_hours_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    orders = Orders.objects.using('db1').filter(
        order_owner=request.user,
        order_started__gte=time_24_hours_ago
        ).extra(select={'order_ended_is_null': 'order_ended IS NULL',},)
```

Note that `Orders` is not a good choice for a variable name, since it refers to another class in the project and begins with caps (generally used for classes), so I've used `orders` instead (different case).